# How to prevent duplicate entries being created in database in quick succession? (JPA)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, transactions

I have a project whereby users post JSON to my API, which is then deserialized to an entity and persisted to the database.
Since running a load testing tool which posts many requests (using the same API key, but as different 'users') in quick succession, I have found that some of my entities are duplicating in the database.

Although my code checks if the object already exists in the database, some of the requests are firing too fast concurrently and they are bypassing the check.

Using an entity manager, I think each request is under its own transaction, but I'm not sure how to 'lock' these transactions. Is there any way to prevent this duplication outside of putting the creation code inside of a general java synchronization block?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you inserted the records to the database ?, em.persist ?, the  @Id is set ?, which is your database ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a relational database (I.E. SQL), then the easiest way is to have the database do it for you. You and a unique constraint to the database table:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_author_name ON authors (first_name, last_name);
```

The above example has database table called "authors". Each author has a first and last name. The constraint prevents the database from storing 2 "Mark Twain"'s.

JPA will throw a PersistenceException and ConstraintViolationException when an attempt to add a duplicate is encountered.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I can't create a unique key on the table, that is the problem (due to other circumstances, in a multi-tenancy database). So I need a way above the database level to lock out other people until the creation is finished.

Comment: Temp table comes to mind... don't insert into the 'real' table but insert into a scratch table and let a process copy over the rows which are not a duplicate. Oh my god I would not want to maintain such a system.

Answer (score 0):

First you can create unique constraints on the table, and if there is a try to insert a duplication, an exception will be thrown.

An other thing is to change your [transaction isolation level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29) to a more strict one (serializable?). But there is a trade-off because it will slow down your access to the DB.

I recommend using the first approach, especially because these conflicts won't occur to often, except in your load tests.

Comment: Transaction isolation level in Glassfish server is already serializable, but database cannot be changed.
See comment on above answer :)

Comment: You could make your check method synchronized, you could write your own insert native SQL, you could allow duplicated records and clean afterwards, but these all are workarounds. And the trade-off again: is it more important to prevent duplicates or to maintain the performace? But I can't think of any JPA specific solution right now.